# Send gridview data to another page through jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a page where I am binding grdiview from server when page is loaded first time but then I have doing client side work  to filter data of grid by adding/deleteing rows from client side..
and here is code for that

```
function onSuccess(response) {
                // debugger;
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var customers = xml.find("ListOfComplaints");

                var appendline = '<tr align="center" style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">' +
                    '             <td align="center"></td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">7</td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">Feb 29, 2016</td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">1000</td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">CompanyName</td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">high discharge pressure</td>' +
                    '             <td align="center">high discharge pressure</td>' +
                    '             </tr>';




                if (customers.length > 0) {  //If Data Found
                    $('[id*=grdlead]').show();
                    $('#tblmessage').hide();

                    $("[id*=grdlead] tbody tr").has('td').remove(); //remove all data rows
                    $("[id*=grdlead] tbody").append(appendline); //append default row


                } else {
                    $('[id*=grdlead]').hide();
                    $('#tblmessage').show();
                }

                var row = $("[id*=grdlead] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                $("[id*=grdlead] tr").not($("[id*=grdlead] tr:first-child")).remove();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    //  debugger;

                    var customer = $(this);
                    //$("td a:first", row).attr('href', 'ComplaintDetails.aspx?id=' + $(this).find("Id").text() + '&hideall=true&cid=' + $(this).find("ProjectId").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("CustomerName").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("EquipModelNo").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("ProjectNo").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("ContractType").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("NoOfDays").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("ExpenAmount").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("ExpenDateFormatted").text());
                    $("[id*=grdlead]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=grdlead] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });

            }
```

So above code is adding /removing grid rows client side.
Now I want to pass grid data as datatable to another page.

So I I do that by server side I mean on click on button to convert gridview data to database, grid show all data.

As very first time Grid is bind from server side .. on in viewstate its has all data but after that I am doing operations on client side.

So when I check gridview rows on server , Its showing all rows which were loaded 1st time.

Now how do solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you cannot add rows to a rendered GridView on the client side.

For one thing it's a security issue and aspx pages will, by default, set the [@Page directive `EnableEventValidation="true" ValidateRequest="true"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx)  to "reduce the risk of unauthorized postback requests and callbacks"

GridViews are not intended to be updated in this way.

A GridView is a data bound control. The only correct way to update a GridView is to make changes to the backing data-store and then rebind the GridView.

Which means you must either use the internal editing features of the GridView, which typically means adding one row of data at a time.

Or you must implement a client side data entry system that is jquery/js based and completely separate from the GridView.  Post that data back to the server, update the GridView data-store and rebind the GridView.